# Dynamic navigation based on rows

Tags: sql, navigation

I'm creating a product rating system, to view a specific product, the following URL is used: `www.example.com/category?product_id=1`. The navigation on each page is simply the current `product_id` + 1 / -1, so if you were to view the example URL I just gave, back would go to `product_id=0` and next would go to `product_id=2`. This works fine, until I delete a product from the database, and that `product_id` no longer exists, the URL it was at just displays a blank page.

What would be the correct way to turn this navigation into a dynamic one, so that it goes to the next `product_id`  rather than a set `product_id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in pseudocode:

next_product_id = query_value("SELECT id FROM product WHERE id > $this_product_id ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1")

previous_product_id = query_value("SELECT id FROM product WHERE id < $this_product_id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1")

Comment: Don't forget to add the "ORDER BY id" for the next id, and "ORDER BY id DESC" for the previous id.

Comment: Only tried this on the first product, so of course it went product_id=1 as the previous, thanks for correcting it.