# Strange query results for dynamic navigation

Tags: php, sql

After asking my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4572167/dynamic-navigation-based-on-rows) I thought the problem was solved, and the answer provided was working when I tried it out.

The issue right now is the navigation selects the previous and next row in the database until the product_id is 100+ then it fails.

Here is the code I'm using to generate the links:

```
$prevProduct = $prod - 3;
$queryNextProductID = 'SELECT product_id FROM products WHERE product_id > '.$prod.' AND   category='.$cat.' LIMIT 1';
$queryPrevProductID = 'SELECT product_id FROM products WHERE product_id < '.$prod.' AND   category='.$cat.' LIMIT '.$prevProduct.',1';
```

The `$queryPrevProductID` returns the previous row in the table until 100+, when it returns an empty result set.

Heres a simplified version of my table to better explain the issue:

```
product_id
1
3
5
80
103
104
```

On the page of `product_id=3` the Previous link will be `1` and the Next link will be `5`
On the page of `product_id=80` the Previous link will be `5` and the Next link will be `103`
On the page of `product_id=103` the Previous link will not be there, and the Next link will be `104`

Any ideas on the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query.  Using the limit with offset is not needed. Also you need to use "ORDER BY product_id" or the next product and "ORDER BY product_id **DESC**" for the previous product.

```
$queryNextProductID = 'SELECT product_id FROM products WHERE product_id > '.$prod.' AND   category='.$cat.' ORDER BY product_id LIMIT 1';
$queryPrevProductID = 'SELECT product_id FROM products WHERE product_id < '.$prod.' AND   category='.$cat.' ORDER BY product_id DESC  LIMIT 1';
```

Comment: Seems my previous answer was wrong, will try this later when I have access to the code again.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the LIMIT like this:

```
LIMIT '.$prevProduct.',1'
```

That will ran into

```
LIMIT 100,1
```

Which doesn't limit your result set to 1 row after row where 'product_id' = 100, but 1 row after 100th row in result.

Just remove the code `'.$prevProduct.'` and use `ORDER BY product_id` to sort results.

Comment: Trying later, how come `LIMIT 97,1` etc (all below 100) works fine then it fails at 100+?